# Why jpa custom query returns more results

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

Spring boot has in memory DB H2. It has table and following data:-

```
    [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "Lokesh",
        "lastName": "Gupta",
        "email": "howtodoinjava@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "email": "xyz@email.com"
    }
]
```

This is my repository with custom jpa query:-

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<EmployeeEntity, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT e FROM EmployeeEntity e WHERE e.firstName like firstName")
    List<EmployeeEntity> findByFirstName(@Param("firstName") String firstName);

    @Query("SELECT e FROM EmployeeEntity e WHERE e.id = id")
    EmployeeEntity findById2(@Param("id") long id);

}
```

Service has following 2 method:-

```
    public EmployeeEntity getEmployeeById2(Long id)  {
    EmployeeEntity employee = repository.findById2(id);
    return employee;
}

public List<EmployeeEntity> findByFirstName(String firstName){
    List<EmployeeEntity> employeeEntities = repository.findByFirstName(firstName);
    return employeeEntities;
}
```

Controller has this:-

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<EmployeeEntity> getEmployeeById(@PathVariable("id") Long id)
        throws RecordNotFoundException {
    EmployeeEntity entity = service.getEmployeeById2(id);

    return new ResponseEntity<EmployeeEntity>(entity, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK);
}

@GetMapping(value = "/fname/{firstName}")
public List<EmployeeEntity> findByFirstName(@PathVariable("firstName") String firstName){
    return service.findByFirstName(firstName);
}
```

When I call findByFirstName. I got both EmployeeEntity.

When I call getEmployeeById. I got error:-

"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"message": "query did not return a unique result: 2; nested exception is javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 2",

I don't know how to write jap custom query correctly so that it returns correct results. How do I get only 1 employee by first name or only 1 employee by it's id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without testing your code, try to use this,

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<EmployeeEntity, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT e FROM EmployeeEntity e WHERE e.firstName like :firstName")
    List<EmployeeEntity> findByFirstName(@Param("firstName") String firstName);

    @Query("SELECT e FROM EmployeeEntity e WHERE e.id = :id")
    EmployeeEntity findById2(@Param("id") long id);

}
```

I added a character `:` before your JPQL variables.

Answer (score 1):

The [named parameters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.named-parameters) in your query are missing a colon. It should be:

```java
@Query("SELECT e FROM EmployeeEntity e WHERE e.firstName like :firstName")
List<EmployeeEntity> findByFirstName(@Param("firstName") String firstName);

@Query("SELECT e FROM EmployeeEntity e WHERE e.id = :id")
EmployeeEntity findById2(@Param("id") long id);
```